# opencms workspace (edit buttons) not displaying

Tags: button, edit, workspace, opencms

I am a newbie in opencms in Tomcat6. I got assigned to review an issue that one of the project is encountering.

In opencms, after we login as Admin to edit the content, the button (a red and white small circle) at the top right hand corner is not showing. Usually, when the button is available (after login), other icons are shown at the top of the page (e.g. edit, info etc) to manage the content.

Please let me know if have any idea.

Thanks in advance ... DB

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if you´re in the offline Project? You can switch between Online and Offline. When you are in the Online Project you cant edit anything.